# What is the difference between 'self' and 'unsafe-inline' in Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: web, content-security-policy

I am trying to understand how Content Security Policies can mitigate XSS-Attacks on Web-Servers. Suppose there is a XSS-vulnerability in an User-Input-Field. It can be used to induce Javascript, such as alert(1) but it can also induce much more serious input, such as a script to exfiltrate Cookies.

When i tried to implement a Content-Security-Policy on that Webserver, i have noticed that both

```
script-src 'self'
```

as well as

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline'
```

prevent the Cookie exfiltration, however 'self' also prevents alert(1) and unsafe-inline doesnt

I am not an expert to Web Engineering, so i do not know what inline or self even refers to. What do they refer to and what are the similarities and differences between the two and how does that relate to the results i got, when i tried to secure my webserver?

Answer (score 0):

**'self'** is just a mnemonic (token) for self domain of website.

For example, the website is accessible as `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, `https://www.example.com`. `http://example.com:8080` etc.

Therefore you have to specify all these host-sources in the `script-src` directive, because you do not know via which URL user will access your website.
Alternatively you can just specify `'self'`, it will mean:

- if user access webpage as `http://www.example.com`, browser will substitute this source instead of `'self'`.
- if user access webpage as `http://example.com:81`, browser will substitute this source instead of `'self'`.

Note that it's better to have relative Urls in the HTML for `'self'` token usage. If user acces webpage as `http://www.example.com` and in HTML code is using `<script src='http://example.com/js/jquery.min.js'>` - the script loading will be blocked.

In the `connect-src` directive the `'self'` token additionally allows `ws://example.com` and `wss://example.com` in the CSP3-compatible browsers.

`'self'` is **safe** because it does not allow XSS via injection of inline scripts or third-party scripts.

> 

**'unsafe-inline'** it's just a token which allows 3 kinds of [inline scripts](https://csplite.com/csp147/) in the webpage.

`'unsafe-inline'` is **unsafe** because it allows XSS through script injection.